# SQL creating a view with calculated column that adds rows

Tags: mysql, sql, calculated-columns, sql-view

I have a table in MySQL that documents the start time and end time of a specific process.
It looks like this:

```
process_id process_start       process_end         data_1   data_2
         1 2017-12-05 15:21:55 2017-12-05 15:39:48 SD12891  8952020517397180000
         2 2017-12-05 15:40:19 2017-12-05 21:56:10 40001067 8952020017390610000
         3 2017-12-05 21:58:10 2017-12-05 22:04:46 SD12667  89014103279450400000
         4 2017-12-05 22:05:50 2017-12-05 22:08:11 40001067 89014103279450400000
```

I want to create a view of this DB, with a new column called "process_time" that will document the hour of the process [LEFT(process_start, 13)], but it will create a row for each hour that the process was up (meaning it will create a new row for every hour between process_start and process_end) and for every new row, all the values in other columns should stay the same. 
So the DB from last picture would look like this:

```
process_id process_time  data_1   data_2
         1 2017-12-05 15 SD12891  8952020517397180000
         2 2017-12-05 15 40001067 8952020017390610000
         2 2017-12-05 16 40001067 8952020017390610000
         2 2017-12-05 17 40001067 8952020017390610000
         2 2017-12-05 18 40001067 8952020017390610000
         2 2017-12-05 19 40001067 8952020017390610000
         2 2017-12-05 20 40001067 8952020017390610000
         2 2017-12-05 21 40001067 8952020017390610000
         3 2017-12-05 21 SD12667  89014103279450400000
         3 2017-12-05 22 SD12667  89014103279450400000
         4 2017-12-05 22 40001067 89014103279450400000
```

How to do something like this?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Tag accordingly.

Comment: You're right, forgot to mention it. it's MySQL

Comment: Please post data as text rather than images, copying that by hand is a pain in the royal...

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have a `numbers` table, this is easy...

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0101c14c048f313b69405a77ad62caee

```
SELECT
  rounded.process_id,
  rounded.process_start,
  rounded.process_end,
  TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR, numbers.id, rounded.process_start_hour)   AS process_hour,
  rounded.data_1,
  rounded.data_2
FROM
(
  SELECT
    *,
    DATE_FORMAT(process_start,'%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')   process_start_hour,
    DATE_FORMAT(process_end  ,'%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')   process_end_hour
  FROM
    document
)
  rounded
INNER JOIN
  numbers
    ON numbers.id <= EXTRACT(HOUR FROM TIMEDIFF(process_end_hour, process_start_hour))
ORDER BY
  rounded.process_id,
  numbers.id
```

I strongly recommend a numbers table for any case where you want to translate one row in to may rows.

Comment: I equally strongly recommend using application code instead ;-)

Comment: @Strawberry : if it's for presentation purposes only, yes.  But, there are many cases where data needs to be quantised prior to processing.  It does very much depend on the purpose.

Comment: OK - I haven't yet encountered that scenario, but look forward to it.

Comment: This indeed looks like a good solution, but unfortunately, I can't create new tables on this DB since it's a server DB.
I can only create views.